# Geeksforgeeks is showing my code as runtime error after submission

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linear-search

This is my code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int srch(vector<int> arr, int ln, int fn)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= ln; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == fn)
        return i;
}
return -1;
}

int main()
{
int t;
scanf("%d", &t);
while (t--)
{
    int n, k;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    printf("%d\n", srch(a, n, k));
}
return 0;
}
```

I am not understanding where is the problem. Here is the problem link [Click here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/searching-a-number/0-number/0). 
Please help me solving this problem. I am not understanding why geeksforgeeks is showing runtime error for this code.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your loops use n-th entry of vector, but

```
vector< int> a(n);
```

has indexes from 0 to n-1

[Notice that the first element has a position of 0 (not 1).](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/)